# libmwi18n.so is missing

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MCR libmwi18n.so file missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972819/mcr-libmwi18n-so-file-missing)

I am running Matlab on a Linux machine. I used mcc compiler to get my .exe file. I run in Matlab command window:

```
mbuild -setup
mcc -m -v test.m
```

However, when I tried to run my exe file "test" from a command line, there was the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmwi18n.so: cannot open shared object 
file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to manually search for `libmwi18n.so` on my machine but it seems that it doesn't exist. Also, I couldn't find information about it on the internet.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Mine's in `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/bin/glnx86/libmwi18n.so`