# shared lib libmwi18n.so not find

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, mcc

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972819/mcr-libmwi18n-so-file-missing)

After reading the answers and comment in the above link I located the 'libmwi18n.so' file and set the `LD_LIBRRY_PATH`, but I'm still getting this error:

```
'error while loading shared libraries: libmwi18n.so: cannot
 open shared object file: No such file or directory'
```

I did the following:

```
locate libmwil8n.so
```

which gives output

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwi18n.so
```

Then I did

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH= /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86
```

and ran the shell program again,

```
./run_app.sh
```

which returns the same error.

Please help me , how can I solve this problem?

Update-

content of the run_spp.sh

```
!/bin/sh
# script for execution of deployed applications
#
# Sets up the MCR environment for the current $ARCH and executes 
# the specified command.
#
exe_name=$0
exe_dir=`dirname "$0"`
echo "------------------------------------------"
if [ "x$1" = "x" ]; then
  echo Usage:
  echo    $0 \<deployedMCRroot\> args
else
  echo Setting up environment variables
  MCRROOT="$1"
  echo ---
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:${MCRROOT}/runtime/glnx86 ;
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${MCRROOT}/bin/glnx86 ;
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${MCRROOT}/sys/os/glnx86;
        MCRJRE=${MCRROOT}/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/lib/i386 ;
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${MCRJRE}/native_threads ;
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${MCRJRE}/server ;
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${MCRJRE}/client ;
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${MCRJRE} ;
  XAPPLRESDIR=${MCRROOT}/X11/app-defaults ;
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
  export XAPPLRESDIR;
 echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH is ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH};
  shift 1
  args=
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
      token=`echo "$1" | sed 's/ /\\\\ /g'`   # Add blackslash before each blank
      args="${args} ${token}"
      shift
  done
  "${exe_dir}"/b $args
fi
exit
```

Comment: You have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH= ...` while it should be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` (note the space after the `=`sign). Is this another typo, or...?

Comment: what does `ls -l /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwi18n.so` return? if it is a symlink, does it (ultimately) refer to an existing file? (try `ldd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwi18n.so`)

Comment: yes it refers to an existing file, then what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should not include the library itself, but rather, the path that *contains* the library. Try:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86
```

or perhaps appending this location to the path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86
```

**EDIT:** (after more info on question provided)

The shell script `run_app.sh` sets up it's own library path, using the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (it is declared in lines 17--24, and overwritten in line 26). This means that anything that is set in your shell before executing the script will be overwritten.

To include the path for `libmwi18n.so`, append the path within the script, after line 17 and before line 26, with:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86
```

(Note: there is also a printout of the LD path so you should be able to tell whether the glnx86 path is present or not).

Comment: In the question linked in your post, the `run_test.sh` script redeclares the LD path (which would overwrite anything set up in your shell before executing the script). Are you doing something similar in `run_app.sh` ?

Comment: yes, the run_app.sh is doing the same thing, should I write the 'libmwi18n.so' path inside the shell program?

Comment: Line 26 of the script will overwrite the LD path with it's own setup path (declared in 17--24).  So yes, try appending the libmwi19n path within the script -- `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86`, around line 18. (There is also a printout of the LD path so you should be able to tell whether the glnx86 path is present or not).

Comment: Thanks you are a life saver.. please update your answer I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `glnx86`, not `glnx68`.

Apologies if that was just a typo in your question.

Comment: ya that was a typo...thanks..but that does not solve the problem

Comment: Oh well, worth checking